# How can I extend a Django Form class?

Tags: python, django

I want to create multiple, similar forms based on this one:

```
class DatabaseForm(forms.Form):
    
    label = "Database label"  # This does not work, but I also can't define it in __init__ method, as I can't access self below in "name" field

    name = forms.BooleanField(label=label, required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", required=False)
```

where I only change the label, like this:

```
class MySQLForm(DatabaseForm):
    label = "MySQL"  # Somehow override label of super class
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does this mean: `I also can't define it in __init__ method, as I can't access self below in "active" field`? There is no "active" field

Comment: Sorry, I renamed it to "name" and forgot the comment.

Comment: You can set the field label in `__init__` and you should have access to "self"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the field label in `__init__` and access the class attribute via `self.label`

```
class DatabaseForm(forms.Form):

    label = "Database label"

    name = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = self.label


class MySQLForm(DatabaseForm):
    label = "MySQL"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the label in the `__init__` constructor:

```
class MySQLForm(DatabaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = 'MySQL'
```

You can also use a parameter in the `DatabaseForm`:

```
class DatabaseForm(forms.Form):
    name_label = 'Database label'
    name = forms.BooleanField(label=None, required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', required=False)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = self.name_label

class MySQLForm(DatabaseForm):
    name_label = 'MySQL'
```